# cifs mounted files : permission denied on modification of newly created file (only)

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs

I'm mounting my NAS with this line in fstab

```
//192.168.1.253/Syno.1 /mnt/net/synonas/syno.1 cifs credentials=/home/rasp/.smbcredentials.synonas,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

I can create, delete, copy files of any size, but whenever I try to modify a newly created one I get a permission denied. Files mounted before are ok since they're mounted with 0777.

I think it has to do with my umask : 0022, the ownership is somehow given to 'users' after creation, so I cannot modify it (rw-r--r--, and I'm logged as 'rasp' not 'users'). 
What troubles me is that I can still delete any file... Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: did you tried gid=rasp and forcegid as options? http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html

Comment: tried the uid version and it worked liked a charm, thank's :)